# Is there something like instanceOf(Class<?> c) in Java?

Tags: java, reflection, instanceof

I want to check if an object `o` is an instance of the class `C` or of a subclass of `C`.

For instance, if `x` is of class `Point` I want `x.instanceOf(Point.class)` to be `true` and also `x.instanceOf(Object.class)` to be `true`.

I want it to work also for boxed primitive types. For instance, if `x` is an `Integer` then `x.instanceOf(Integer.class)` should be `true`.

Is there such a thing? If not, how can I implement such a method?

Comment: handling boxed classes is a little messy

Answer (score 197, accepted):

[Class.isInstance](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance(java.lang.Object)) does what you want.

```
if (Point.class.isInstance(someObj)){
    ...
}
```

Of course, you shouldn't use it if you could use `instanceof` instead, but for reflection scenarios it often comes in handy.

Comment: @Ahamed it's probably slower, but what's worse is it's harder to understand! If there is a very simple way to do something - like `if (a instanceof Point)` - but you do it in a more convoluted way, whoever reads the code is bound to think "oh, there has to be a reason for this being done the hard way", and then jump to the docs to find out how `Class.isInstance` differs from `instanceof`. You waste your colleagues' time.

Answer (score 21):

> I want to check if an object o is an
>   instance of the class c or of a
>   subclass of c. For instance, if p is
>   of class Point I want
>   x.instanceOf(Point.class)

Um... What? What are o, p and x?

> I want it to work also for primitive
>   types. For instance, if x is an
>   integer then
>   x.instanceOf(Integer.class) and also
>   x.instanceOf(Object.class) should be
>   true.

No. It shouldn't even compile. Primitives are not objects, and you cannot call methods on them.

Anyway, there are three things, one of which can definitely achieve what you want (they differ somewhat in where exactly the apply:

- The `instanceof` operator if you know the class at compile time.
- [Class.isInstance()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance(java.lang.Object)) if you want to check an object's class against a class not known at compile time.
- [Class.isAssignableFrom()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom(java.lang.Class)) if you want to check the assignability given two class objects.

Answer (score 10):

```
x instanceof Integer
x instanceof Object
```

you just have to use the right syntax

for primitve types, you have to do it completely different. Since you cannot create methods for them , you need a class that keeps the method. So instead of "x.instanceOf(Integer.Class)", you have to call "MyClassComparer.instanceOf(x, Integer.Class)" or something like that. This could easily be implemented by overloading methods, but I fail to see a case when that functionality would be desireable at all.

Answer (score 5):

In fact in Java there's a boolean operator called instanceof which can be used to determine if an object is an instance of a class, an instance of a subclass, or an instance of a class that implements a particular interface.

```
if(obj instanceof SomeClass) {
    // Do something
}
```

The Java Tutorial has a [good example](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/examples/InstanceofDemo.java) of this operator

Comment: you cannot use instanceof with primitive types

Comment: He confused primitive types with objects. Please read... "For instance, if x is an integer then x.instanceOf(Integer.class) and also x.instanceOf(Object.class) should be true." Shame on you down-voting all the answers

Comment: Seconding (sp) the suggestion of using the Java Tutorial. It is a good reference for learning the language itself.

Answer (score 3):

The right-hand side of `Class.isAssignableFrom()` is the subclass

So, for Objects `obj` and superclass `Class<?> superCls`

`superCls.isAssignableFrom( obj.getClass() )`

and

`obj instanceof superCls`

are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
if (foo instanceof classNameYouWantToCheck)
```

Comment: you cannot use instanceof with primitive types

Comment: The class was just to show he should write the class name there. I'll fix it

Answer (score 0):

"I want it to work also for primitive types. For instance, if x is an integer then x.instanceOf(Integer.class) and also x.instanceOf(Object.class) should be true."

Why? Primitive types and reference types are completely separate. A primitive int is not a subtype of Integer nor Object. The type of a primitive value is always known statically at compile time, so there is no point in testing its type. Sure, you can box a primitive value and then test its type:

```
(Integer)5 instanceof Integer
```

But what would be the point?

Answer (score -1):

I think you're confused about instanceof for raw objects and generic ones

```
obj instanceof Class
obj instanceof Class<?> // this is the one you want
```

Comment: You cannot use generics on the right hand side of the instanceof operator due to type erasure.

Comment: No, it is _you_ who are confused about it.  You have to use the raw type after `instanceof`.