# Finding all instances of a given class in an array

Tags: java

I have a program where I need to find all instances of a class within an array. I would like to create a method that does this for me. For instance, if I have the array

```
Object[] arr = {"mystring", new Boolean(false), new Integer(4), new Character('i')}
```

and I called this method with argument of String (I'm not sure what the type of my argument should be, actually), it would return an array of `{"mystring"}`.

I've tried things like

```
public void printInstancesOf(Class c, Object[] array)
{
    for (Object obj : array)
    {
        if (obj instanceof c)
        {
             System.out.println(obj);
        }
    }
}
```

But that doesn't even compile. Does anyone know how to do this? Or is it not possible to do?

Comment: what do you want to do with the instances? Just print them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there something like instanceOf(Class<?> c) in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949352/is-there-something-like-instanceofclass-c-in-java)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you want [Class.isInstance(Object o)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance%28java.lang.Object%29):

> Determines if the specified Object is assignment-compatible with the object represented by this Class. **This method is the dynamic equivalent of the Java language instanceof operator**. The method returns true if the specified Object argument is non-null and can be cast to the reference type represented by this Class object without raising a ClassCastException. It returns false otherwise.

```
if (c.isInstance(obj) {
    System.out.println(obj);
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can detect subclasses by trying to cast using `try{ c.cast(obj); 
System.out.println(obj); } catch (ClassCastException e) {}`

Answer (score 2):

That doesn't work since it's testing if `obj` is an `instanceof` the literal `c` class. I don't have a Java environment handy, but I believe something like

```
if (obj.getClass().equals(c)) {
```

should do the trick. This probably doesn't work with subclasses though, but that shouldn't be an issue here.

Edit: as others have pointed out

```
if (c.isInstance(obj)) {
```

is the better choice

The larger question is...*why are you doing this*? Trying to simulate loose typing in Java is an admirable goal but usually a very bad idea. Use proper polymorphism and/or generics instead (with custom classes).

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like idiomatic Java. You would normally only build arrays for specific classes and not mix different classes like String, Boolean, Integer, Character.

This is normally a code smell.

If you have a hierarchy like

AFoo, BFoo, CFoo -> extending Foo, and have them in an Array, you would make them react significantly to a message:

```
for (Foo foo : foos) 
    foo.react (param);
```

AFoos could then react in another way than BFoos. Else use instanceof:

```
for (Foo foo : foos) 
    if (foo instanceof BFoo)
        barDoSomethingWith (foo, param);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
private <E> List<E> findInstances(Class<E> type, Object[] arr) {
    List<E> instances = new ArrayList<E>();
    for(Object o : arr) {
        if(type.isInstance(o)) {
            instances.add((E)o);
        }
    }
    return instances;
}
```