# Check instanceof a type from name

Tags: java, class, types, instanceof

I want to do this: Get a type from a name, and the fail a test if the message.
I suppose it doesn't work because clazz is not a type. But how do I go about this?

```
Class<?> clazz=Class.forName("com.android.test."+myEnum.toString());

if(myObj instanceof clazz)
    Assert.fail();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949352/is-there-something-like-instanceofclass-c-in-java second google result...

Answer (score 2):

Use isInstance (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance%28java.lang.Object%29):

```
    Class<?> clazz=Class.forName("java.lang.String");
    String myObj = "string";        
    if(clazz.isInstance(myObj)){
       System.out.println("Its String Class");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Class<?> clazz=Class.forName("com.android.test."+myEnum.toString());

if(clazz.isAssignableFrom(myObj.class))
   Assert.fail();
```

See its JavaDoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom(java.lang.Class)