# What data type to store an other data type?

Tags: java, class, variables, instanceof

**Note:** I am not asking what types can be used to store a class name nor I am asking for work-arounds to store class names such as reflection or using `String`s. This is also not a question on asking how to use `instanceof` operator.

Consider this example:

```
A a = new A();
Class c1 = A.class;
System.out.println(a instanceof c1);    //Does not Work

Class c2 = A.class.getClass();
System.out.println(a instanceof c2);    //Does not Work

class A{}
```

I know the above codes will fail. But I am curious whether it is possible to  store a class such that it can work as though I am typing out the class name itself.

```
System.out.println(a instanceof A);    //This will work
```

---

Can we hold (class)`A` with some variables `xx` so that this will work?

```
System.out.println(a instanceof xx);
```

**My question is:** Is it possible to store `A` with a variable such that the compiler will treat that variable as though it is seeing `A`?

*Note: I am not asking how to store object of A. I am asking is it possible to store A itself.*

Comment: You mean like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949352/is-there-something-like-instanceofclass-c-in-java)?

Comment: You need to use `Class.isAssignableFrom`. Read the [JavaDoc for `Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html).

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use the `instanceof` operator. The second operand of `instanceof` *must* be a class name, it cannot be an arbitrary expression, in particular, it cannot be a variable.

The grammar states that the syntax for `instanceof` is:

```
RelationalExpression:
    RelationalExpression instanceof ReferenceType
```

And `ReferenceType` can only be the name of a class or interface, an array type or a type variable (*not* a normal variable). So, it doesn't matter which type you use to declare that variable you *can't* achieve what you want due to a fundamental limitation of the (current) grammar.

Also `instanceof` has to perform some checks at *compile-time* and, hence, it must be able to determine which type you want to use as second operand *at compile-time*, but using an expression would allow to change that type dynamically at runtime.

However you can use the dynamic equivalent, the [`isInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance-java.lang.Object) method:

```
System.out.println(c1.isInstance(a));
```

The documentation explictly says so:

> Determines if the specified Object is assignment-compatible with the
>   object represented by this Class. **This method is the dynamic
>   equivalent of the Java language `instanceof` operator.**

Answer (score 1):

Use this for the general case:

```
System.out.println(c1.isAssignableFrom(a.getClass()));
```

Or this for the instance:

```
System.out.println(c1.isInstance(a));
```