# ArrayList of multiple types that inherits one abstract class

Tags: java, arraylist

I made one `account` abstract class that is the super class of another 3 different account classes.

Then in a `manageAccount` class I have to create an ArrayList that stores account classes. In this class I have a method that should find a specific type of class, for example, it returns every `EspecialAccount` classes in the arraylist.
My arrayList is of type `Account` and I can't see how I can add the classes that inherit it. Is it possible?

```
public class ManageAccounts {

    ArrayList<Account> aList = new ArrayList();


    public String SearchSpecialAccounts(){
        for(int i=0; i<aLista.size(); i++){
            //how can I search in the arrayList all of the specialAccounts?
        }
    }
```

I'm a beginner at JAVA, please be nice.

Comment: is specialAccounts  is other class extending account ?

Comment: post your full code for more clarity

Comment: Please check the following SO answear:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/949367/11947303

Comment: It’s extending specialAccount, there are another two classes extending it, so the arraylist is of account classes, I also want to know if the arraylist can accept objects of these other classes

Comment: it's extending Account... I tried to edit the comment but  it didn't let me

Answer (score 2):

Just filter it out

```
 ArrayList<Account> accounts; all accounts

List<SpecialAccount> filteredAccounts= sccounts.stream().filter(SpecialAccount.class::isInstance).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [instanceof](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26806_01/wlp.1034/e14255/com/bea/p13n/expression/operator/Instanceof.html) like:

```
for(int i=0; i<aLista.size(); i++){
      if(aLista.get(i) instanceof specialAccounts)
        //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check the return type of searchSpecialAccounts();

```
package com;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ManageAccounts {

    ArrayList<Account> aList = new ArrayList<>();

    List<SpecialAccounts> specialAccountsList = new ArrayList<>();
    public List<SpecialAccounts> searchSpecialAccounts(){
        for(int i=0; i<aList.size(); i++){
            //how can I search in the arrayList all of the specialAccounts?
            if(aList.get(0) instanceof SpecialAccounts) {
                specialAccountsList.add(specialAccountsList.get(i));
            }
        }
        return specialAccountsList;
    }
}

class SpecialAccounts extends Account {

}
class Account {

}
```

Comment: It works but it does not respect the object programming fashion very well, because of `ìnstanceof`.

Answer (score 0):

My proposal an *Object-oriented programming*  :

1. add an abstract method to `Account` class : `public abstract String getType();`
2. implements this method in `EspecialAccount` as follow :

```
public String getType() { return "EspecialAccount"; }
```

3. then, call `searchSpecialAccounts()` :

```
public String searchSpecialAccounts() {
  for(Account acc : aLista){
    if(acc.getType().equals("EspecialAccount")) {
      // acc is of searchType type, great !
    }
  }
}
```

If you want to specify a *default value* for `getType()`, you can implement it on the abstract class and then override it for special accounts classes only.