# How to assign instanceof type to a variable?

Tags: java, instanceof

I am wondering if it is possible and how to store a `type` reference into a variable so that it can be later used with the `instanceof` operator.

For example

```
Book book = new Book("My Favourite Book", "Some Author");

BookType bookType = Book;

if(book instanceof bookType){
    // Do something
}
```

Instead of having to hard code it:

```
Book book = new Book("My Favourite Book", "Some Author");

if(book instanceof Book){
    // Do something
}
```

Is it possible to get the `Book type` from `Book.class` maybe using reflection?

I did not found much about this topic.

Note that this is not the same as using

```
Book.class.isInstance(book);
Object value = Book.class.cast(book);
```

because I would lose all the methods of the Book class.

Comment: actually `Book.class` is the type - it can be stored in a variable `Class<?> bookType = Book.class`  and used like in `if (bookType.isInstance(book))` (Note: often there are better solution {more OO} instead of using reflection)

Comment: As reflection should only be the really last resort, what is your "true" goal? `book.getClass()` returns the `Class<Book>` instance, but that cannot be used with the `instanceof` operator. The `instanceof` operator would even raise a compile time error if the expression on the left side would cause a `ClassCastException` at runtime, when you cast it to the type on the right side of the operator. With a variable on the right side, this would not be possible.

Comment: I need to assign the object/value parsed from a json to a field of type Book (or other types accordingly) of another class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest to what you originally asked<sup>1</sup> for is something like this:

```
   Class<?> clazz = Book.class;

   Object someObject = new Book(...);
   
   if (clazz.isInstance(someObject)) {
      Object instanceOfClazz = clazz.cast(someObject);
      // ...
   }
```

(Note that this Q&A - [Is there something like instanceOf(Class<?> c) in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949352) - directly answers the question in the your question title.)

But you objected that the result of the `cast` call:

> *"would lose all the methods of the `Book` class"*.

First of all that is not technically correct.  The object that `instanceOfClazz` refers to is still and will always remain a `Book`.  It still has and will always have all of the methods of a `Book`.

But you do have a point (I think).  You cannot use the `cast` call's result effectively in the above code because you assigned it to a variable whose type is `Object`.  And you cannot call `Book` methods via a variable / value whose *static* type is `Object`.

If instead we had written this:

```
   Class<Book> clazz = Book.class;

   Object someObject = new Book(...);
   
   if (clazz.isInstance(someObject)) {
      Book book = clazz.cast(someObject);
      // call some `Book` methods.
   }
```

Now you can call `Book` methods on `book`.  But the gotcha is that we had to write `Class<Book>` instead of `Class<?>` (or `Class`) to make that work.  So we have ended up wiring the class name `Book` into the code anyway.  Ooops!

The fundamental problem is that Java code cannot make regular method calls on an object unless the compiler knows what its type is ... and that it has those methods.  If you want to invoke `Book` methods in cases where the static type of the variable is (say) `Object`, then you have to use reflection to do it.  Something like this:

```
  if (clazz.isInstance(someObject)) {
      Method method = clazz.getMethod("setNosPages", int.class);
      method.invoke(someObject, 99);
  }
```

and deal with the various exceptions that that might throw.

Basically, you refer to the class and methods by name in the code, or you use reflection.

---

> *"I need to assign the object/value parsed from a json to a field of type Book (or other types accordingly) of another class."*

It won't work.   Java is a statically typed language<sup>2</sup>. Think of another way to solve the problem.  For example, use reflection to assign to the field.

---

<sup>1 - That is ... what the words of your question originally asked!

2 - OK ... that is over-simplifying.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

If you are only going to use it for `instanceOf` i think you should think about using this structure:

```
Object someObject = new Book(...);

if(someObject instanceOf Book book) {
    //use book as variable
    book.read();
}
```

To my knowledge this is called Pattern Matching is is possible in Java 14.